# VPN-Sharing via WLAN Internet Sharing

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, sharing, vpn

I am connected to a vpn network throught the ethernet port. And I want to share these connection over a WLAN internet sharing my iPhone.

Configuration:

- OSX: Mavericks (Version 10.9.4)
- VPN: OpenVPN (with client Tunnelblick oder Viscosity)
- Interface: TAP

I tried a couple of tutorials, but nothing works:

- http://rodrigo.sharpcube.com/2010/06/20/using-and-sharing-a-vpn-connection-on-your-mac/
- http://www.sparklabs.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1129

I also tried the tool IceFloor (hanynet), with the NAT combination and a shared vpn connection:
[image]

After assign these services, it looks so:
[image]

And my interfaces are:
[image]

Is these configuration all, or have i missed something?

Answer (score 1):

Try with "share internet connection from tap0 to computers using en0", which is actually what you want, tap0 being the vpn and en0 being wifi.